numpy array slice then assign to itself
Why the following code does not return [1,4,3,4]? Hasn't a already changed during the reversed order assignment?
a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
a[1::]=a[:0:-1]

The result is:
array([1, 4, 3, 2])


You're right that a changes during the assignment, which in turn affects the view whose elements you're assigning into a. If NumPy didn't have special handling for this case, you could indeed see array([1, 4, 3, 4]) as a result.
However, NumPy checks for this case. If NumPy detects that the RHS of the assignment may share memory with the array being assigned to, it makes a copy of the RHS first, to avoid this kind of problem:
if (tmp_arr && solve_may_share_memory(self, tmp_arr, 1) != 0) {
    Py_SETREF(tmp_arr, (PyArrayObject *)PyArray_NewCopy(tmp_arr, NPY_ANYORDER));
}



Hasn't 'a' already changed during the reversed order assignment?

No, a[:0:-1] is first evaluated, yielding array([2, 3, 4]). In an assignment, the right-hand side is first evaluated, then the left part.
Then, it replaces the last 3 items of a, modifying it to be:
array([1, 4, 3, 2])


That would make sense for lists, but for arrays, a[0:-1] is a view. Updates to a affect the view.

@user2357112 in a python assignement, the RHS is evaluated before the LHS. If a was updated during the assignment, this would be a paradox.

It's evaluated before the LHS, but what it evaluates to is a view. Python does not take a snapshot of the RHS's state; the view is passed directly to the LHS's __setitem__ method.
